# Reading and Meaning of 町の主だった幹部

Tags: kanji, readings

> 今回は、町の主だった幹部は、全員顔を揃えていた。

How would you read 主 here? And does 町の主だった幹部 mean "the main leaders of the town"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

主だった is read 「おもだった」, and means "to serve an important position inside a group". Your interpretation of the phrase as "the main leaders of the town" sounds good to me.

> おも‐だ・つ【主立つ／重立つ】
>   ［動タ五（四）］集団の中で重要な地位を占める。中心となる。ふつう、「おもだった」の形で用いる。「会社の―・った人」
>   https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%BB%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4/